# Save execution state of a python script using pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I have a Python script running on my laptop and currently have it suspended.  Is it possible to use Pickle to save the state of execution so that I can make changes to the script and resume execution using the same variables and from the same spot where I last suspended execution?  Any ideas on how exactly to accomplish this?

Edit: I am running a Recurrent Neural Network and would like to save the state of the weight matrices and word vectors in the middle of execution.  The changes to the code are fairly trivial: for example, changes to the print statements.

Comment: A quick way of adding a persistence layer is to use y_serial module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/y_serial/) but there is no magic - you still have to program storing and loading objects. Solution to your problem depends on what kind of changes you want the code to support. Objects' serialization will not support changing their implementation. Please be more specific.

Comment: It sounds like you want [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), which lets you stop a program mid-execution and navigate through it (though I'm not sure you can change the program on the fly). Have you looked at using that?

Comment: pdb would be a good solution, but I'm not sure that it can be attached to the process after it has already begun.  Even if it were possible, is there a way to insert breakpoints while the process is live?